# Install AJAX.NET 2.0 Extension in .NET 3.5 environment

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

Do I need to install AJAX.NET 2.0 Extension, Futures, Samples, and Source Code even after I installed .NET Framework 3.5 SP1?

I'm using Server 2003, and installed dotnet2.0. Then I installed Visual Studio 2008 that brought .net 3.5 to my system.

I'm planning to publish an ASP.NET web app in my server :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Ajax.Net functionality is built into the .net framework 3.5.

If your code is developed for a .Net 3.5 application then you will not need it.

If you code is developed for a .Net 2 application, then you will need to download the ajax extensions.